# Searching from three different tables with three different columns

Tags: mysql

How to search three different tables with three different columns? The current command:

```
$sql="select t1.brand_name,t2.category_name from brand_data_add AS t1 
      LEFT JOIN category_add_data AS t2 ON t1.brand_name=t2.category_name 
      UNION select t1.brand_name,t2.category_name from brand_data_add AS t1 
      RIGHT JOIN category_add_data AS t2 ON t1.brand_name=t2.category_name";
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP or MySQLi?

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        workouts.name,
        workouts.description,
        `user`.user_email
    FROM
        workouts
    LEFT JOIN `user` ON
        workouts.created_by = `user`.iduser
UNION
    SELECT
        workouts.name,
        workouts.description,
        `user`.user_email
    FROM
        workouts
    RIGHT JOIN `user` ON
        workouts.created_by = `user`.iduser) AS main_table
WHERE
    user_email LIKE '%gmail%';
```

Explanation:

1. You should enclose your union query with bracket
2. Fetch the fields with `SELECT` clause
3. Use the `WHERE` clause to do the conditional filter in virtual table `main_table` (union of two table)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.brand_name,t2.category_name, t3.? from brand_data_add AS t1 
      LEFT JOIN category_add_data AS t2 ON t1.brand_name=t2.category_name 
      LEFT JOIN t3 on t3 on t3.? = t?
      UNION select t1.brand_name,t2.category_name, t3.?  from brand_data_add AS t1 
      RIGHT JOIN category_add_data AS t2 ON t1.brand_name=t2.category_name"
      RIGHT JOIN t3 on t3 on t3.? = t?
```